# python NameError: name '<anything>' is not defined (but it is!)

Tags: python, nameerror

**Note: Solved. It turned out that I was importing a previous version of the same module.**

It is easy to find similar topics on StackOverflow, where someone ran into a NameError. But most of the questions deal with specific modules and the solution is often to update the module.

In my case, I am trying to import a function from a module that I wrote myself. The module is named InfraPy, and it is definitely on sys.path. One particular function (called listToText) in InfraPy returns a NameError, but only when I try to import it into another script. Inside InfraPy, under `if __name__=='__main__':`, the listToText function works just fine. From InfraPy I can import other functions with no problems. Including `from InfraPy import *` in my script does not return any errors until I try to use the listToText function.

How can this occur?
How can importing one particular function return a NameError, while importing all the other functions in the same module works fine?

Using python 2.6 on MacOSX 10.6, also encountered the same error running the script on Windows 7, using IronPython 2.6 for .NET 4.0

Thanks.

If there are other details you think would be helpful in solving this, I'd be happy to provide them.

As requested, here is the function definition inside of InfraPy:

```
def listToText(inputList, folder=None, outputName='list.txt'):
    '''
    Creates a text file from a list (with each list item on a separate line). May be placed in any given folder, but will otherwise be created in the working directory of the python interpreter.
    '''
    fname = outputName
    if folder != None:
        fname = folder+'/'+fname
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    for file in inputList:
        f.write(file+'\n')
    f.close()
```

This function is defined above and outside of `if __name__=='__main__':`

I've tried moving InfraPy around in relation to the script. The most baffling situation is that when InfraPy is *in the same folder* as the script, and I import using `from InfraPy import listToText`, I receive this error: `NameError: name listToText is not defined`. Again, the other functions import fine, they are all defined outside of `if __name__=='__main__':` in InfraPy.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are receiving.

Comment: can you procure the source code of the __InfraPy__ module , it can be helpful here; but my first guess is that maybe you define the function __listToText__ in side the bloc `if __name__=='__main__':` have you ?`

Comment: I suggest you post definitions of the functions and/or classes in the module (i.e., the 'def' or 'class' lines, but without the bodies), showing at least one that is accessible from outside the module, and one that isn't.

Comment: Can you show the output of `import InfraPy; print InfraPy.__dict__`?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've tried to respond to your requests. for ChristopheD, `print InfraPy.__dict__` showed everything but listToText.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could happen if the module has [`__all__`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) defined

Alternatively there could be another version of the module in your path that is getting imported instead of the one you are expecting

Is the `NameError` about `listToText` or is it something inside the function causing the exception?

Comment: Thanks gnibbler, it seems to be another version of the module on sys.path. When I create a new folder with InfraPy and a test script, and deleted some .pth files from my site-packages directory, it worked fine. when I removed InfraPy from that new folder, and restored the .pth files, I received the same errors that initiated this post. Found and solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In addition the `__all__` variable gnibbler mentioned you could also have a problem with a InfraPy.pyc file lying around somewhere.

I'd recommend putting a `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` first in the InfraPy.py file to make sure you are in the right file, and step through the definition of InfraPy.py to see what is happening. If you don't get a breakpoint, you are importing another file than you think.

You can also `dir(InfraPy)` after importing it, and check which file you are actually importing with `InfraPy.__file__`.

Can't think of any more import debugging hints right now. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Lennart, the `InfraPy.__file__` tip in particular is really useful in this case. I did some fishing for InfraPy.pyc and found one that might have been causing the problem.