# PyDBG Python 2.7 error: "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, pydbg

I am trying to use PyDBG with Python 2.7. I believe it is installed correctly.

```
import pydbg
dbg = pydbg()
```

Produces error when run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[path removed..]\pydbg.py", line 1, in <module>
import pydbg
File "[path removed..]\pydbg.py", line 5, in <module>
dbg = pydbg()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pydbg import pydbg
dbg = pydbg()
```

In general, you should add the name of an imported module *before* calling any of its members:

```
import pydbg
dbg = pydbg.pydbg()
```

**EDIT :**

Also, make sure that the file that contains your script is *not* named `pydbg.py`, because it'd conflict with the name of the module you're trying to import. As it turns out, that was the problem.

Comment: The second one returns the same error and the first one returns "from pydbg import pydbg ImportError: cannot import name pydbg"

Comment: I suspect the module is not correctly installed. Just to be sure, try this: `from pydbg import *`

Comment: from pydbg import *
dbg = pydbg()

gave error: "NameError: name 'pydbg' is not defined"

Comment: It's a common problem and not specific to `pydbg`, take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686525/python-nameerror-name-anything-is-not-defined-but-it-is) for possible solutions.

Comment: If it is any indicator when I go in cmd and run python and import pydbg and enter `pydbg().attach(3866)` it seems to attach to the process fine with no error

Comment: Wait, are you running the script from inside a file? Did you name the file `pydbg.py`? if that's the case, rename it, it's conflicting with the module

Comment: Well now I feel like an idiot. Thanks that worked brilliantly.

Comment: Don't worry :) . Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to do:

```
   dbg = pydbg.pydbg()
```

unless you specifically import pydbg from pydbg with

```
   from pydbg import pydbg
```

I prefer the former.

Comment: Tried the second: from pydbg import pydbg
ImportError: cannot import name pydbg

Comment: @user1415944 same problem with both? .. let me look into this a bit more.

Comment: The pydbg.pydbg() returns the error in original post. The from pydbg import pydbg prints "cannot import name pydbg"

Comment: @user1415944 Could you tell me the of your source file, and how you are running it?

Comment: Thanks for you help, it turned out it was conflicting with the name of the file I was running it from, also pydbg.py. Oops..

Comment: @user1415944 .. yes, that's what I thought .. hence my last question. Glad it worked out.